# How To Use Custom Tax of a Post Type

Tags: posts, taxonomy, customization

I've defined a custom post type.  I've defined a custom taxonomy for this custom post type.  I've populated the custom taxonomy.  How do I make the list of custom taxonomy values show up in the admin edit page of the custom post type? So I can assign one or more custom taxonomy values to the custom post type post?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can either set the `taxonomies` parameter of [`register_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type), which accepts an array of taxonomies, or set object type to your custom post type (or array of types) when you [register your taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy), or you can use the [`register_taxonomy_for_object_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type) function.

Comment: I've already tried the first method of setting the taxonomies param of register_post_type.  The only thing that shows up in the admin edit page is a heading for my custom taxonomy with a text entry box to add new custom taxonomy values.  But I am expecting to see a list check boxes, one for each pre-existing custom taxonomy value.  Just like you see when editing a normal post and you see a list of pre-existing cateogry values.

Comment: @Greg Turner - as @Kevin Langley Jr. mentions in his answer, you're taxonomy is defined as non-hierarchical (like the default post tags), set it to `hierarchical => true` and it will behave like categories, with a tree of check boxes for adding terms.

Comment: Thank you!!! Setting hierarchical => true is the missing piece in my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

When registering your custom taxonomy make sure to set heirarchical to true and you will get a taxonomy similar to Categories.

[Codec: Register Taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)

Comment: If this worked, please accept the answer.